# Add a list of string to each row in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and i want to add a new column 'cities' so when i do type(df['cities'][0]), i should get a list and not string. What should be the correct approach? df['cities'] = cities does not work

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name':['john', 'ray', 'tony']}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

# add a list to each row
```

The output should be like this:

[image]

```
cities = ['NY', 'LN', 'PK', 'SF']
```

Comment: i have added expected output

Comment: There is probably a big issue with the accepted solution. Try `df.loc[0, 'cities'][0] = 'LA'`. It change all the values because all lists are a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every row to contain a list, then you have to assign a column (in your example, 'cities') a list of lists:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['john', 'ray', 'tony']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# add a list to each row
cities = ['NY', 'LN', 'PK', 'SF']
df['cities'] = [cities for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: Take care, your lists share the same reference `cities`. Try `df.loc[0, 'cities'][0] = 'LA'`

Comment: That's a good point - thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['cities'] = np.tile(cities, len(df)).reshape(-1, len(cities)).tolist()
print(df)

# Output
   name            cities
0  john  [NY, LN, PK, SF]
1   ray  [NY, LN, PK, SF]
2  tony  [NY, LN, PK, SF]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` with `axis = 1` can work:

```
data = {'name':['john', 'ray', 'tony']}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

cities = ['NY', 'LN', 'PK', 'SF']
df['cities'] = df.apply(lambda x: cities, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
    name    cities
0   john    [NY, LN, PK, SF]
1   ray     [NY, LN, PK, SF]
2   tony    [NY, LN, PK, SF]
```